# Webhooks on BigCommerce blueprint site not responding quickly ( delay in response )

Tags: webhooks, bigcommerce, blueprint

My issue is related to webhooks on a site built on BigCommerce bluprint.

I have created webhooks on a blueprint site. The issue is either webhooks responds late or sometimes fails at all. When it responds late, it takes 15 to 30 mins ( or sometimes more than too ).

Ideally, it should respond instantly. As I am not facing the above mentioned issue on a Stencil website.

Can anybody guide me what is the cause or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're hitting the callback retry mechanism:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#callback-retry-mechanism

Webhooks do dispatch in near-real time, but if the hooks service doesn't receive a 200 response from your server within 10 seconds, the retry mechanism will kick in. Webhook payloads will retry according to a schedule of increasing intervals, and any undelivered hooks will queue up during that time. The hooks service will keep trying until a 200 response is received from your server, or until the final retry interval (48 hours since the first delivery) at which point the hook is temporarily disabled.

It would be a good idea to check that your server is responding to webhook payloads right away (and not running any other processes first) to make sure that the hooks service receives a 'successful' response within the 10 second window.